# Trying to display the background color in the if condition

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to use the background color (with class- badge & badge primary) for the text display, if the if condition is met in PHP. But seems to be some syntax problem. The code is working without hyperlink tags.

```
 <?php
      $active_info=$this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->student_session;
                if ($active_info['student_session'] == 1)
                 <a class="badge badge-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">echo get_phrase("Active Login"); </a>
                  if ($active_info['student_session'] == 2)
                 echo get_phrase("Inactive Login");
                 ?>
```

Comment: For to be sure to propose the good answer can you paste more code ? But in fact you have a big syntax problem with your code

Comment: edited and added more clarity to the question and code

Comment: For other people read your question it's good to mark answer are validate your problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in rendering html from PHP script. This should work...

```
//your code
if ($active_info['student_session'] == 1){
             echo '<a class="badge badge-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">' . get_phrase("Active Login") . '</a>';
}
//your php code continues
```

Comment: You are life saviour, thank you so much brother ..... it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the portion of code you submit the right syntax was :

```
    <?php
      $active_info=$this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->student_session;
                if ($active_info['student_session'] == 1)

                  echo '<a class="badge badge-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">' . get_phrase("Active Login").'</a>';
if ($active_info['student_session'] == 2)
                 echo get_phrase("Inactive Login");
                 ?>
```

Explain:

For print text to PHP you need to use echo or other function dedicated to that. Use ' or " to encompass your string and make it readable.